# Why were good guys depicted as religious and the bad guy as an atheist?

Tags: fantastic-voyage

In the 1966 movie, *Fantastic Voyage* an American scientist (Dr. Benes) is nearly assassinated by Soviet forces and rendered comatose as a result.

A team of American surgeons agree to shrink using a technology Dr. Benes has created and go into his body to operate the blood clot in his brain in order to save his life.

En route, inside a blood vessel a discussion about God, soul, and creation takes place. All the medical staff there believe in God and soul, while only one of them (Dr. Michaels) who turns to be a Soviet spy trying to kill Dr. Benes near the end of the movie denies the existence of God and souls.

Why did the director and screenwriter decide to depict the bad guy as an atheist and the good guys as religious persons? Wasn't it an act of demonizing atheist people?

Comment: The movie was made in 1966.  That should be enough explanation

Comment: Usually it's the other way around; the religious people are depicted as the crazy fanatics.  But if the guy was a Soviet, it would have been weird for him to be religious.  The atheism of the USSR was well known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Freedom of Religion is one way in which we defined ourselves against the Soviets.**

The story already sets up the bad guys as Soviets and the good guys as Americans. Since the freedom to practice religion was part of what defined the West against the Communist Bloc, the filmmakers used that as a way of illustrating a difference and foreshadowing the double cross.

Was it demonizing atheists? Maybe you're being a little thin-skinned here. Is having a Christian villain demonizing Christians? Is having a male villain demonizing men? Someone has to be the bad guy and the bad guy has to have some characteristics that might be shared with some in the audience. That's not an attack on the people who share some characteristic. If it was, then having a villain who was human at all would always be "demonizing" someone.